# Jquery not firing after radiobutton checked

Tags: jquery, radio-button

So i have a little problem with getting my jquery to fire after i check a radio button. I followed the jsFiddle but for some reason it's not working for me. Itried two ways i found by some googling but i have no clue why it's not working

```
<input type="radio" id="hourlyRadio" name="group1" class="group1" value="hourly"></input>
    <input type="radio" id="dailyRadio" name="group1" class="group1" value="daily"></input>
    <input type="radio" id="weeklyRadio" name="group1" class="group1" value="weekly"></input>
    <input type="radio" id="monthlyRadio" name="group1" class="group1" value="monthly"></input>
```

and this is my jquery as it is now, the alert is there to see if it actually fires:

```
$('input:radio[name="group1"]').change(
    function(){
        if($('#hourlyRadio')).is(':checked')){
            alert('i just came to say hello');
            }
    });
```

And i tried this before but alas to no avail:

```
    $("#hourlyRadio").change(function() {
    if($("#hourlyRadio").prop("checked")){
        alert("THIS");
        alert("IS");
        alert("WORKING");
        $(hourly).show();
        $(daily).hide();
        $(weekly).hide();
        $(monthly).hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: `input` is a self-closing tag!

Answer (score 4):

```
$('input:radio[name="group1"]').change(function(){
    if ($('#hourlyRadio')).is(':checked')) {
                         ^ remove this
        alert('i just came to say hello');
    }
});
```

You have an extra bracket, causing a syntax error

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hV6C6/1/)

Comment: hmmm strange it's not working for me even after removing the bracket... could it be a problem with jquery 1.7.2?

Comment: @JeroenVinckx Check your console for errors. Add some logging in the change handler to make sure it's actually getting triggered. Make sure the DOM is ready before executing your jQuery

Comment: it's executing all other jquery just fine, just this piece does not want to work, and there are no errors. it might just be due to platform i'm using. would not surprise me.

Comment: It isn't because of the version of jQuery you're using, the code would work just fine. Make sure you're not duplicating element IDs. The problem is definitely elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

change it to this

```
$('input[name="group1"]').click(function(){

    if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).attr('id') == 'hourlyRadio' ){
            alert('i just came to say hello');
    }
});
```

here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qKXsj/)